# Why can't download the magnet with aria2c command?

Tags: bash, magnetometer, magnet-uri

The `Battlestar Galactica` here
http://kickasstorrentsan.com/usearch/Battlestar%20Galactica/
can be downloaded  with deluge.

[image]
[image]

Now i scrap the magnet with firebug on the web page.
[image]

It can be verified that the magnet is :

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2D2CAE6AC83800490327547053597BAFF6701C2F&dn=battlestar+galactica+season+1+s01+1080p+bluray+x265+hevc+aac+5+1+joy+utr&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce
```

The bash script were written as following:
[image]

1.the $url variable is right address for magnet.
2.aria2c command can be executed correctly.
3.`aria2c $url` has beeen executed for about one hour.Why nothing can be dowlonaded?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but it is suggested that you do `aria2c "$url"`

Comment: aria2c "$url"  can't work ,it was tested ,failed.

Comment: The point was not `aria2c "$url"` will work, even in a working version it is suggested to double quote  `$url` to avoid word splitting.

Comment: I have given you the gift after my verification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This [`page`](https://nurtya.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/ubuntu-app-aria2-howto-use/) says, you need to enable DHT option while downloading using magnet-links:-

This [`official documentation`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html) page says, it is enabled by default from version `1.25.0`

> --enable-dht[=true|false]
>   Enable IPv4 DHT functionality. It also enables UDP tracker support. If a private flag is set in a torrent, aria2 doesn't use DHT for that download even if true is given. Default: true

Checked the release notes from [`GitHub`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/aria2/files/stable/aria2-1.16.5/README.rst/view), couldn't find the exact release since the flag `--enable-dht` has been made to `true`.

Upgrade to the latest version to have the flag enabled by default (or) enable it explicitly if you are using an older version.

```
aria2c --enable-dht=true "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:2D2CAE6AC83800490327547053597BAFF6701C2F&dn=battlestar+galactica+season+1+s01+1080p+bluray+x265+hevc+aac+5+1+joy+utr&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce"
```